# Inserted data using phpmyadmin and one column keeps repeating the value of the first test case that i tried

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, phpmyadmin

my php script is like:

```
$mobnumber = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["mobnumber"]);
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["name"]);
$state = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["state"]);
$role = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["role"]);
$designation = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["designation"]);
$organisation = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["organisation"]);
$mail = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["mail"]);
$addr = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["addr1"].", ".$_POST["addr2"].", ".$_POST["addr3"].", ".$_POST["addr4"].", ".$_POST["addr5"]);
$sql="INSERT INTO admin_reg VALUES (null, '$mobnumber', '$name', '$state', '$role', '$designation', '$organisation', '$mail', '$addr')";
```

my form space for the mobnumber field is:

```
<label class="description" for="mobnumber">Contact Number </label>
<div>
   <input id="mobnumber" name="mobnumber" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
</div>
```

No matter what value i enter in the mobile number field, im getting it as the random mobile number of the first test case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO admin_reg (
          -- Enter your table fields name here
      ) VALUES (
          null,
          '{$mobnumber}',
          '{$name}',
          '{$state}',
          '{$role}',
          '{$designation}',
          '{$organisation}',
          '{$mail}',
          '{$addr}'
      )";
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply mate! But I changed the datatype of the column to VARCHAR and it is working now.